# Use Checkbox with service

Tags: java, android, android-checkbox

Is it possible to use a `Checkbox` with Service in Android? Because I am using the following code and the Service does not care if I check the `Checkbox` or not.

```
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
  CheckBox deleteImage = view.findViewById(R.id.deleteImage);
  if (deleteImage.isChecked()) {
      for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles())  {
          if (fileEntry.exists()) {
             if (fileEntry.delete())
                 System.out.println("Image deleted");
             else
                 System.out.println(fileEntry + " not able to delete");
          }
     }
 } else
     System.out.println("Don't delete images");
```

The Service should delete the Images if during the wait from the thread the `Checkbox` gets checked. It only works with `deleteImage.setCheck(true);`

Comment: use `setOnCheckedChangeListener`

Comment: Does that work if change during a `TimeUnit.Milliseconds.sleep()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use this for listening checkbox changes

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (b) {
                for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles())  {
                    if (fileEntry.exists()) {
                        if (fileEntry.delete())
                            System.out.println("Image deleted");
                        else
                            System.out.println(fileEntry + " not able to delete");
                    }
                }
            } else
                System.out.println("Don't delete images");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Does this work if i check the Checkbox during  `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(Math.max(date-System.currentTimeMillis(),0));` because i just tried it and it does not work for me :(

Comment: because the Code should only be executed at a secific time of the day and the code is also in a external thread not in the main thread.

Comment: yes the above code is in a Background Service and if the Checkbox gets checked the Service should delete the Images the next time it reaches this code because the Service executes the code at a specific time of the day once a day. Is this even possible because I read that it's not possible to compair UI's with Services. I hope you can help me with this :)